# Axon framework handling UnexpectedRollbackException in EventHandler

Tags: exception, event-sourcing, axon, axon-framework

When dealing with exception thrown in @EventHandler methods, we use @ExceptionHandler reside in the same class to catch "known exceptions" and take a resilience manner for handling those broken "events".

```java
    @Slf4j
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Service
    public class PersonProjection {

        private final PersonRepository personRepository;

        @EventHandler
        public void on(PersonCreatedEvent event) throws CheckedBusinessException {
            if(event.someUncheckedRulesViolated()) {
                throw new CheckedBusinessException(event);
            }
            Person person = new Person();
            // this will throw exception if not checked like above.
            Objects.requireNonNull(person.getIdentityCard());
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(event, person);
            personRepository.save(person);
        }

        @ExceptionHandler
        public void handle(CheckedBusinessException exception) {
            log.error("CheckedBusinessException handled");
        }
    }
```

This way, we can log and ignore such accidently happened historical events, because Axon will only retry those Runtime exceptions.

But if we have a DataAccessException/ConstraintViolationException (Such as duplicate key) occurring at the personRepository.saveAndFlush()'s committing phase, we are not able to handle the exception like this.

```java
        @EventHandler
        public void on(PersonCreatedEvent event) {
            try {
                Person person = new Person();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(event, person);

                // we use saveAndFlush() to catch the DataAccessException.
                personRepository.saveAndFlush(person);

            } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
                log.error("catch DataAccessException.");
                throw new CheckedDataAccessException(event);
            }
        }

        @ExceptionHandler
        public void handle(CheckedDataAccessException exception) {
            // Why Axon will still enter Retry mode event if we handled this type of exception here?
            log.error("CheckedDataAccessException handled");
        }
```

After check some of Error handling logic, we know there's an UnexpectedRollbackException occurring, so that Axon will retry it anyway.

The question is, how should I handle these events if we know the exception could happen only upon committing the unitOfWork?

I have created a repo to demo this behavior here at:
[Github Repository showcase_axon_exception](https://github.com/JuntaoWu/showcase_axon_exception).

```
2021-11-01 11:54:37.177  WARN 16076 --- [cation.query]-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2021-11-01 11:54:37.177 ERROR 16076 --- [cation.query]-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry 'string' for key 'ux_person_information_name'
2021-11-01 11:54:37.746 ERROR 16076 --- [cation.query]-0] i.c.s.a.query.PersonEventHandler         : CheckedDataAccessException handled

info.cepheus.showcase_axon_exception.coreapi.exception.CheckedDataAccessException: DataAccessException occurred while persist event: { personId: f16f76f8-db33-422f-80a0-4d0f15ea19a0, name: string }
    at info.cepheus.showcase_axon_exception.infrastructure.PersonQueryServiceImpl.save(PersonQueryServiceImpl.java:49) ~[main/:na]
    at info.cepheus.showcase_axon_exception.infrastructure.PersonQueryServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1c640112.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at info.cepheus.showcase_axon_exception.infrastructure.PersonQueryServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3de709c.save(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at info.cepheus.showcase_axon_exception.application.query.PersonEventHandler.on(PersonEventHandler.java:40) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedMessageHandlingMember.handle(AnnotatedMessageHandlingMember.java:144) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$NoMoreInterceptors.handle(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:372) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.lambda$handle$0(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:352) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MessageHandlerInterceptorDefinition$ResultHandlingInterceptorMember.handle(MessageHandlerInterceptorDefinition.java:80) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.doHandle(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:358) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.lambda$handle$1(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:353) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.InterceptorChainParameterResolverFactory.callWithInterceptorChain(InterceptorChainParameterResolverFactory.java:75) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.handle(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:352) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.lambda$handle$0(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:352) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MessageHandlerInterceptorDefinition$ResultHandlingInterceptorMember.handle(MessageHandlerInterceptorDefinition.java:80) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.doHandle(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:358) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.lambda$handle$1(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:353) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.InterceptorChainParameterResolverFactory.callWithInterceptorChain(InterceptorChainParameterResolverFactory.java:75) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$ChainedMessageHandlerInterceptorMember.handle(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:352) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter.java:94) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.SimpleEventHandlerInvoker.handle(SimpleEventHandlerInvoker.java:112) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.MultiEventHandlerInvoker.handle(MultiEventHandlerInvoker.java:89) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.lambda$null$1(AbstractEventProcessor.java:165) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:57) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.interceptors.CorrelationDataInterceptor.handle(CorrelationDataInterceptor.java:65) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:55) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.extensions.tracing.OpenTraceHandlerInterceptor.handle(OpenTraceHandlerInterceptor.java:106) ~[axon-tracing-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:55) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.lambda$new$1(TrackingEventProcessor.java:185) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:55) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.lambda$processInUnitOfWork$2(AbstractEventProcessor.java:173) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.executeWithResult(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:86) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.processInUnitOfWork(AbstractEventProcessor.java:159) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processBatch(TrackingEventProcessor.java:451) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:294) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1005) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1151) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2021-11-01 11:54:38.788 ERROR 16076 --- [cation.query]-0] i.c.s.config.MyAxonErrorHandler          : Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.axonframework.spring.messaging.unitofwork.SpringTransactionManager.commitTransaction(SpringTransactionManager.java:80) ~[axon-spring-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.spring.messaging.unitofwork.SpringTransactionManager$1.commit(SpringTransactionManager.java:63) ~[axon-spring-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.UnitOfWork.lambda$attachTransaction$0(UnitOfWork.java:273) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.MessageProcessingContext.notifyHandlers(MessageProcessingContext.java:72) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.lambda$notifyHandlers$2(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:155) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.notifyHandlers(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:155) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.changePhase(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:222) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commitAsRoot(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:83) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commit(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:71) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.executeWithResult(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:111) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.processInUnitOfWork(AbstractEventProcessor.java:159) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processBatch(TrackingEventProcessor.java:451) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:294) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1005) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1151) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2021-11-01 11:54:38.788  WARN 16076 --- [cation.query]-0] o.a.e.TrackingEventProcessor             : Releasing claim on token and preparing for retry in 4s
2021-11-01 11:54:38.798  INFO 16076 --- [cation.query]-0] o.a.e.TrackingEventProcessor             : Released claim
```

Comment: Would it be reasonable to skip/filter the events instead of catching the exceptions in your case? I am trying to understand your use case (for catching the exceptions per event handler) a little better, as I am in doubt about what to recommend.

Comment: So, I have taken some time diving into Axon Framework to figure out where this might happen. I have a ton of hunches, but no real answer, yet. To simplify my process, would you provide a sample repository that consistently replays the exception?

Comment: Hi @Steven, thanks for such recommendation, I have provided a sample repository for further investigating.

Comment: It's reasonable to skip the events, actually, we also do a normal ignore & return for such events can be checked. It's just normal downstream branch here. The event.someUncheckedRulesViolated() here I mean is that sometimes we found a historical event is unexpected, e.g. will always throw a NPE. So we check and mark it as a BusinessError for further handling.

Comment: Sadly, I am rather busy helping tons of people use Axon. As it stands, running your application stalls quite harsh on the connection bit with MySQL. Would you be able to update your sample either by removing MySQL (H2 is less setup work, for example) or by removing the password logic? I assume neither is needed to replay the issue locally.

Comment: Apart from that, there's one thing on the sample that's not clear to me. Is the `CheckedDataAccessException` Exception Handler in the `PersonEventHandler` invoked at all? And, if there's any more fleshed out stack-trace that also reference Axon code, that might help too to figure out why the retry mechanism in the Tracking Event Processor is reached.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience here. I've updated the config which removed the password. now we can connect to the MySQL server with empty-password root user.

Comment: @Steven , And yes, the CheckedDataAccessException-handler was invoked indeed.